# How to re-write file extension in URL while keeping the same query string

Tags: mod-rewrite

I just ported the ColdFusion code to PHP on an old site that I built a few years ago. Now I want to make sure that any existing links that people might have bookmarked still work. Here's an example of the old URL structure:

```
http://example.com/cfm/recDetailsP.cfm?recID=449
```

This page is now on the following URL:

```
http://example.com/recording.php?recID=449
```

I know I can use mod_rewrite in a .htaccess file but I find it quite unintuitive when regular expressions are involved and in this case they are because the recID can be any number. Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is simple

```
RewriteRule ^cfm/recDetailsP\.cfm$ /recording.php [L]
```

the query string is copied unchanged by default.

I found the answer here http://simonecarletti.com/blog/2009/01/apache-rewriterule-and-query-string/